# Display nested lists with CSS using focus-within

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, nested-lists

I'm looking to try to create an HTML list whereby nested `ul` elements are only displayed when focussed-within, using CSS's `focus-within` pseudo-class.

The idea is that using keyboard tabbing only (ignoring mouse interactions for now) you should be able to focus along the list items from one to the next, and when you focus on the a button element it reveals the next level of list items.  That part works fine.  However, when you then tab away from the button element it should keep the next `ul` visible because the focus *should* be on the first `a` element in the nested `ul`, so the nested `ul` *should* be determined as being focussed within.

I have it so that this works as a demonstration when I set background colours on the `ol`s.  The natural state is white background, but the 'open' state is demonstrated by a red background.  This works fine:

```css
.menu ul ul {
                background: #fff;
            }
            .menu button:focus + ul,
            .menu ul ul:focus-within {
                background: #f00;
            }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 1’</button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                            <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 2’</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 3’</button>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 1’</button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                            <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 2’</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 3’</button>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

So when the nested lists turn red, that's when they're visible, otherwise they're not visible.

However, when I replace the background colours with `display: block` and `display: none` it doesn't work:

```css
.menu ul ul {
                display: none;
            }
            .menu button:focus + ul,
            .menu ul ul:focus-within {
                display: block;
            }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 1’</button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                            <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 2’</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 3’</button>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="has-children">
                    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 1’</button>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="has-children">
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                            <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 2’</button>
                            <ul>
                                <li class="has-children">
                                    <a href="#">Level 3</a>
                                    <button>Show sub-menu for ‘Level 3’</button>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#">Level 4</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Level 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

It's as if the `display: none` state kicks in before the focus can move to the nested links.  Could anyone confirm that I'm barking up an impossible tree here, or whether there's a way to get this working?

EDIT: The other thing to note is that if you keep tabbing, it maintains the correct position in the first level of list items, so it does feel like the focus is getting to the first anchor element of the nested lists, but it just doesn't recognise that the nested `ol` has a focus within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve it using `focus-within` on the `li` element rather than the `ul` element:

```
    .menu ul li ul {
        display:none;
    }
    .menu button:focus + ul,
    .menu ul li:focus-within > ul {
        display: block;
    }
    .menu ul li:focus-within a:focus ~ ul {
        display: none;
    }
```

Still don't 100% understand why the original scenario doesn't work, but this is a workable solution.